# Boolean fields are set to false on copyToRealmOrUpdate realm

Tags: java, realm

I don't know why I see strange behavior when I am trying to update a row in Realm without updating boolean field are set as false.
Here am not updating my boolean fields i.e `noti` and `adult`:-

**CASE 1:**

```
 Realm.init(context);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    UserDetails m2= new UserDetails();
    m2.setUserid(1);
    m2.setSort(paths_Vvalue[position]);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(m2);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

After execution of this code they(`noti` and `adult`) are saved as **false** even before they were as **true**

> is this a Bug?
>   everything Works fine if i add and update these fields like:-

**CASE 2:**

```
 Realm.init(context);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    UserDetails res = realm.where(UserDetails.class).equalTo("userid", 1).findFirst();
    UserDetails m2= new UserDetails();
    m2.setUserid(1);
    m2.setSort(paths_Vvalue[position]);
    m2.setAdult(res.getAdult());  //setting boolean
    m2.setNoti(res.getNoti());  //setting boolean
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(m2);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Everything works fine in this case but still,
Am i doing something wrong at **case 1** or is this a bug or a functionality of realm?
any hint will be great thanks!

Comment: What is `UserDetails` class?

Comment: realm object class @M.Prokhorov

Comment: So, it's an unmanaged Realm object, and those do not have any constructors. Which means your primitive boolean values are initialized with their defaults, which is `false`. And after update is requested, values are updated with what is contained within that instance. It works precisely as expected.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks the issue was noti and adult fields were missing from my constructor that's why this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are overwriting ("updating") your `UserDetails` with the same primary key and an object with following values

```
UserDetails m2= new UserDetails();
m2.setUserid(1);
m2.setSort(paths_Vvalue[position]);
//m2 adult is default `false`
//m2 noti is default `false`
...
realm.insertOrUpdate(m2);
```

You are updating the existing object with an (unmanaged) item where those field values are `false`, so of course it will be `false`.

Comment: by default, they are true not false!

Comment: Why would they be true? Unless you have a default constructor that sets them to true, they are false.

Comment: Am doing that on first run

Comment: No, you're not. If it's not in the default constructor then you aren't.

Comment: please can you tell the correct way to update with existing fields and yes userid is primary key

Comment: Query existing object in a transaction and modify the fields you want to change the values of on that object